# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: j. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

t fails to deserialize/prase this json, ive tried multiple combinations with different methods to try and make this work but nothing seems to do it...

The code im using

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();


var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wc.DownloadString("http://services.runescape.com/m=website-data/playerDetails.ws?names=[%22" + Username.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%22]&callback=jQuery000000000000000_0000000000&_=0"));
```

the json its trying to deserialize...

```
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":false,"name":"Sudo Bash","clan":"Linux Overlord","title":"the Troublesome"}]);
```

Comment: A json should start with a `{` or `[`

Comment: So i guess ill have to trim the whole jQuery000000000000000_0000000000() part from the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Json specification you can see that `[` indicates the begining array of json objects while `{` indicates beginning of new json object.

Your json string starts with `[` so it can contains more json objects ( because it's an array and it contains `jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(` which is your query string parameter. To get rid of the query string garbage you should find out the scheme of that garbage and then to process json object I would recommend you to deserialize your json string into `List<JObject>` using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` method if your json string starts with `[` ( use standard type if it is starting with `{` );

Example :

```
string url = // url from @Darin Dimitrov answer
string response = wc.DownloadString(url);
// getting rid of the garbage 
response = response.Substring(response.IndexOf('(') + 1);
response = response.Substring(0, response.Length - 1);
// should get rid of "jQuery000000000000000_0000000000(" and last occurence of ")"
JObject result = null;
if(response.StartsWith('['))
{
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(response)[0];
}
else 
{
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to deserialize is not `JSON` but rather `JSONP` (which is JSON wrapped in a function call).

Remove this parameter from your query string:

```
&callback=jQuery000000000000000_0000000000
```

and you should be good to go with a properly formatted JSON:

```
var url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=website-data/playerDetails.ws?names=[%22" + Username.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%22]&_=0";
var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wc.DownloadString(url));
```

Comment: Already attempted this.. throws 404... i also tried to trim the jQuery000000000000000_0000000000 part from the string.. neither seemed to work..

Comment: In this case you should consult the documentation of the remote endpoint that you are trying to call and see how it can be called so that it returns pur JSON instead of JSONP. If the service doesn't support JSON response you might need to do some string manipulation in order to remove the function name from the response before feeding it to your JSON deserializer.